# MariaDB - How to add index to a generated VIRTUAL column

Tags: mariadb

I am Using MariaDB 10.11.6 and have a large table (~1.4bn rows) with log data.

I am trying to add an index to a `VIRTUAL` column created with:

```
ALTER TABLE log_table ADD COLUMN Days int(11) UNSIGNED AS (TO_DAYS(LogTime)) VIRTUAL INVISIBLE;
```

Based on the MariaDB [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/) for *generated* columns it should be possible, but I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1904 (HY000): Key/Index cannot be defined on a virtual generated column
```

The table is using the "Aria" storage engine, and generated columns should be supported:

> InnoDB, Aria, MyISAM and CONNECT support generated columns
>
> — [Generated Columns - Storage Engine Support](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/#storage-engine-support)

Adding an index on the generated column should be supported:

> Defining indexes on both VIRTUAL and PERSISTENT generated columns is supported.
>
> — [Generated Columns - Index Support](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/#index-support)

Note: The table in question is also partitioned on a `datetime` column, using code like `VALUES LESS THAN TO_DAYS('2024-02-15')` as per [Rick James' guide to partition maintenance](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Could you please help me find out why I cannot create an index on the generated virtual column?

Best regards
-Bjarne

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE for this table before your attempt to index the column and the index creation query which causes an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an open issue: [MDEV-18812, Add support for generated indexed virtual columns to aria](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18812). It was created 2019-03-04, so I would not hold my breath in wait for a solution

For the sake of it, I created a [Fiddle, MariaDB 10.9](https://dbfiddle.uk/H9zYgszC) for aria (which fails)  and innodb (that succeeds)

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I thought it might be a bug or not implemented in Aria.

Comment: STORED  INVISIBLE seems to work, so that might be a work around for you

Comment: @lennart-slava-ukranini I think it's called PERSISTENT in MariaDB. It _does_ work with persisten, but given the number of rows (1.4 billion) this will make the table a lot larger on disk. During creation of this generated column a full table scan is needed, which makes the table unavailable for a long time (4-6 hours).